# Alter FBSDKLoginButton logout dialogue for iPad - iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I am implementing single sign on with Facebook via `FBSDKLoginButton` and `FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate`.

After successful login, the button changes to logout - Upon tapping it, Facebook implementation presents a `UIAlertController` in action sheet style to confirm logout. This crashes the app on iPad with error:

`'NSGenericException', reason: 'Your application has presented a UIAlertController (<UIAlertController: 0x7fce37e4f3d0>) of style UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet. The modalPresentationStyle of a UIAlertController with this style is UIModalPresentationPopover. You must provide location information for this popover through the alert controller's popoverPresentationController. You must provide either a sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.  If this information is not known when you present the alert controller, you may provide it in the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method -prepareForPopoverPresentation.'`

Is there a way to alter the hidden implementation of this `UIAlertController.popoverPresentationController` to indicate the `sourceView`?

Comment: I have the same problem...